# How to sort array by array field value javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array:

```
var objs = [ 
    { id: 'X82ns', name: 'james', presence: 'online'     },
    { id: '8YSHJ',    name: 'mary', presence: 'offline'   },
    { id: '7XHSK', name: 'rene', presence: 'online' }
];
```

I want to sort the array so it returns a new array by 'presence': 'online' users displaying first before offline items.

So if sorted, it should return something like this:

```
var objs = [ 
    { id: 'X82ns', name: 'james', presence: 'online' },
    { id: '7XHSK', name: 'rene', presence: 'online' },
    { id: '8YSHJ',    name: 'mary', presence: 'offline' }
];
```

Something like this:

```
const newArray = objs.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.presence === 'online') {
        return 1;
      } else if (b.presence === 'offline') {
        return -1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    })

return newArray;
}
```

What is the right way to get the expected result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `localeCompare` method.

```js
var objs = [ { id: 'X82ns', name: 'james', presence: 'online' }, { id: '8YSHJ', name: 'mary', presence: 'offline' }, { id: '7XHSK', name: 'rene', presence: 'online' } ];

objs.sort((a,b) => b.presence.localeCompare(a.presence));
console.log(objs);
```

Don't forget that the `sort()` method *sorts* the elements of an array *in place* so you do not need to use `const newArray = objs.sort...`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sort` function with condition of **a.presence < b.presence** because of `online` is bigger than `offline` (`f` and `n`)

```js
var objs = [ 
    { id: 'X82ns', name: 'james', presence: 'online'     },
    { id: '8YSHJ',    name: 'mary', presence: 'offline'   },
    { id: '7XHSK', name: 'rene', presence: 'online' }
];

objs.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.presence < b.presence;
});

console.log(objs);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply compare the String with `>`, `=` and `<`

```js
let objs = [ 
    { id: 'X82ns', name: 'james', presence: 'online'     },
    { id: '8YSHJ',    name: 'mary', presence: 'offline'   },
    { id: '7XHSK', name: 'rene', presence: 'online' }
];

let res = objs.sort((a,b) => a.presence > b.presence ? -1 : a.presence == b.presence ? 0 : 1);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let objArr = [ 
    { id: 'X82ns', name: 'james', presence: 'online'     },
    { id: '8YSHJ',    name: 'mary', presence: 'offline'   },
    { id: '7XHSK', name: 'rene', presence: 'online' }
];

let onlineArr = objArr.filter(x=>x.presence === 'online')
let offlineArr = objArr.filter(x=>x.presence === 'offline')
console.log([...onlineArr, ...offlineArr])
```

In terms of readability, you can split them into two array and using array destructuring to join them at last

Answer (score 1):

You could take an object with the order as values and sort by it. This allowes to use a default value for unknow values.

```js
var array = [{ id: 'X82ns', name: 'james', presence: 'online' }, { id: '8YSHJ', name: 'mary', presence: 'offline' }, { id: '7XHSK', name: 'rene', presence: 'online' }],
    order = { online: 1, offline: 2, default: Infinity };
    
array.sort((a, b) => (order[a.presence] || order.default) - (order[b.presence] || order.default));

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `>` sign to get `online` first and `offline` at the end. You can also create a separate function `sortFn` so this logic can be reused for multiple arrays.

```js
var objs = [ 
    { id: 'X82ns', name: 'james', presence: 'online'     },
    { id: '8YSHJ',    name: 'mary', presence: 'offline'   },
    { id: '7XHSK', name: 'rene', presence: 'online' }
];

function sortFn(a, b){
  return b.presence > a.presence;
}
objs.sort(sortFn);
console.log(objs);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually compare the items, and if they are now the same, then check for `presence`

```js
var objs = [ 
    { id: 'X82ns', name: 'james', presence: 'online'     },
    { id: '8YSHJ',    name: 'mary', presence: 'offline'   },
    { id: '7XHSK', name: 'rene', presence: 'online' }
];

const newArray = objs.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.presence !== b.presence) {
        return a.presence === "online" ? -1 : 1;
      }
      return 0;
});


console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const newArray = objs.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.presence === 'online' && b.presence === 'offline') {
        return 1;
      } else if (b.presence === 'online' && a.presence === 'offline') {
        return -1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    })

return newArray;
}
```

Comment: @Oj Obasi please test this and feedback me, this based on your solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```html
var objs = [ 
    { id: 'X82ns', name: 'james', presence: 'online'     },
    { id: '8YSHJ',    name: 'mary', presence: 'offline'   },
    { id: '7XHSK', name: 'rene', presence: 'online' }
];

var statusOrder = ["online", "offline"];

objs = objs.sort(function(a, b) { 
     return statusOrder.indexOf(a.presence) - statusOrder.indexOf(b.presence);
 });
```

Even shorter with ECMAScript6:

```html
objs = objs.sort((a, b) => statusOrder.indexOf(a.presence) - statusOrder.indexOf(b.presence));
```

Answer taken from [Faly's answer to another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46466513/javascript-sort-array-of-objects-on-key-values).

Answer (score 0):

**@Oj Obasi**, try the below code.

> It uses **map()** method defined on arrays.

```js
    var objs = [ 
        { id: 'X82ns', name: 'james', presence: 'online' },
        { id: '8YSHJ',    name: 'mary', presence: 'offline' },
        { id: '7XHSK', name: 'rene', presence: 'online' }
    ];

    /* Pretty printing objs array*/
    console.log(JSON.stringify(objs, null, 4))  // Before modification (sorting)
    /*
    [
        {
            "id": "X82ns",
            "name": "james",
            "presence": "online"
        },
        {
            "id": "8YSHJ",
            "name": "mary",
            "presence": "offline"
        },
        {
            "id": "7XHSK",
            "name": "rene",
            "presence": "online"
        }
    ]
    */

    objs.map((item, index) => { 
     if(item.presence === 'online') { // online, add to front then remove this item from its current position
      objs.splice(0, 0, item) // add at front
     } else { // offline, push at end then remove this item from its current position
      objs.splice(objs.length, 1, item) // push at end 
     }
     objs.splice(index, 1) // remove
    })

    /* Pretty printing objs array */
    console.log(JSON.stringify(objs, null, 4))  // After modification (sorting)
    /*
    [
        {
            "id": "X82ns",
            "name": "james",
            "presence": "online"
        },
        {
            "id": "7XHSK",
            "name": "rene",
            "presence": "online"
        },
        {
            "id": "8YSHJ",
            "name": "mary",
            "presence": "offline"
        }
    ]
    */
```